# $\big(1+\frac {C_0}{C_1}\big) \big(1+\frac {C_1}{C_2} \big) \cdots \big(1+\frac {C_{n-1}}{C_n} \big) =?$

Tags: binomial-coefficients

If $(1+x)^n =~~ ^nC_0 ~+~ ^nC_1~x ~+~  ^nC_2 x^2~+~\cdots+~ ^nC_n x^n $, then the value of  :

$$\bigg(1+\dfrac {C_0}{C_1}\bigg) \bigg(1+\dfrac {C_1}{C_2} \bigg) \cdots  \bigg(1+\dfrac {C_{n-1}}{C_n} \bigg)$$  is =?

**Attempt:**

I have been unsuccessful in most of my attempts with regard to this question.

Could someone please give me some hints on how to move forward.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: just curious, can you tell me the source of this problem ?

Comment: It's the graduate level entrance exam for my university

Comment: well this was given in a mock test for an entrance exam in my coaching school :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have $\dfrac{\dbinom{n}{k-1}}{\dbinom{n}k} = \dfrac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k+1)!} \cdot \dfrac{k!(n-k)!}{n!} = \dfrac{k}{n-k+1}$.
Hence, we have
$$1+\dfrac{\dbinom{n}{k-1}}{\dbinom{n}k} = 1 + \dfrac{k}{n-k+1} = \dfrac{n+1}{n-k+1}$$
Hence, we have
$$\prod_{k=1}^n \left(1+\dfrac{\dbinom{n}{k-1}}{\dbinom{n}k}\right) = \prod_{k=1}^n \dfrac{n+1}{n+1-k} = \dfrac{(n+1)^n}{n!}$$

Answer (score 2):

To supplement the first answer posted above, a more "visual" approach is given below.

Assume the following notation:
$\displaystyle C_r= {^nC_r}=\binom nr$

From the identity $\displaystyle \binom nr+\binom n{r+1}=\binom {n+1}{r+1}$
we have $\displaystyle C_r+C_{r+1}= {^{n+1}C_{r+1}}$

Hence 
$$\begin{align}
&\quad\bigg(1+\frac{C_0}{C_1}\bigg)
\bigg(1+\frac{C_1}{C_2}\bigg)
\bigg(1+\frac{C_2}{C_3}\bigg)
\cdots
\bigg(1+\frac{C_{n-1}}{C_{n}}\bigg)\\
&=
\bigg(\frac{C_0+C_1}{C_1}\bigg)
\bigg(\frac{C_1+C_2}{C_2}\bigg)
\bigg(\frac{C_2+C_3}{C_3}\bigg)
\cdots
\bigg(\frac{C_{n-1}+C_n}{C_n}\bigg)\\
&=
\frac{^{n+1}C_1}{\;\;^nC_1}\cdot
\frac{^{n+1}C_2}{\;\;^nC_2}\cdot 
\frac{^{n+1}C_3}{\;\;^nC_3}\cdot 
\cdots \cdot
\frac{^{n+1}C_n}{\;\;^nC_n} \\
&\color{lightgray}{=
\frac{\frac{n+1}1}     {\frac n1}\cdot
\frac{\frac{(n+1)n}{2}}{\frac{n(n-1)}{1\cdot 2}}\cdot 
\frac{\frac{(n+1)n(n-1)}{1\cdot 2\cdot 3}}{\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{1\cdot 2\cdot 3}}\cdot\cdots\cdot 
\frac{\frac{(n+1)n(n-1)\cdots 2}{1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdots n}}{\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots 1}{1\cdot 2\cdots n}}}\\
&=
\frac{n+1}n\cdot 
\frac{n+1}{n-1}\cdot
\frac{n+1}{n-2}\cdot\cdots\cdot 
\frac{n+1}{1}\\
&=\frac{(n+1)^n}{n!} \qquad\blacksquare
\end{align}$$